# Bouncing ball slightly leaves the screen frame in Spritekit

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, game-engine, game-physics

I have the following code that simulates bouncing balls. Although I mentioned that the bodies should be kept within in the self.frame, they leave (the whole ball is not visible anymore) and then comeback. It's as the frame has larger width than the visible borders. However, height is totally fine.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {    
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)
            let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)
            sceneBody.friction = 0
            self.physicsBody = sceneBody

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            var pos = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
            ball.position = pos
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
            ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.9
            ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

            self.addChild(ball)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add `scaleMode = .ResizeFill` and change `frame` to `view.frame` in `didMoveToView`

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly.

Comment: I doubt it works perfectly.  @0x141e, Shouldn't ever use view.frame, it should be the scene frame,  and explain .ResizeFill to the poor guy, because now when he switches devices hes going to be lost again